# achartengine setting the distance between the X Title and the X Text Label

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there a way to set the distance between the X Title and the X Text label.  They are overlapping on the x axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea would be that you use the `renderer.setXLabelsPadding()` method to control the x axis labels location. Make sure you are using a recent 1.1.0 version.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version it was 1.1.0.rc2 after setting the padding it still has the title and the labels overlapping.  I do appreciate your quick response though.  On Motorola phones I can add a newline character and that fixes it but on all other phones it has no effect.  That was at least my cheap way of trying to fix it.

Comment: Download the latest one here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/ What padding setting have you used?

Comment: @Dan Is it possible to decrease the distance between x axis value??